# Many embedded attributes reference the same Embeddable class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

I want to create a class Exporter that has two phones numbers: landline and mobile.
Knowing that the phone number is composed of the country code and number,I created an `Embeddable` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddablePhone implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6573789138766984739L;
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_COD")
    private String countryCode;
    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String number;

    public EmbeddablePhone () {
    }

    //getters and setters 
}
```

How can I use this Class in the class Exporter to reference the landline and mobile:

```
public class Exporter implements Serializable{

.....
......

    @Embedded
    private EmbeddablePhone  landLine;
    @Embedded
    private EmbeddablePhone  moblePhone;
    public Exporter () {

    }

    //getters and setters

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `@AttributeOverride` annotation.

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
  @AttributeOverride(name="countryCode", column=@Column(name="MOB_COUNTRY_COD")),
  @AttributeOverride(name="number", column=@Column(name="MOB_NUMBER"))})
private EmbeddablePhone moblePhone;
```